# Zoom in on the pointer not on the origin of the uploaded image in fabric js Also to set the maximum zoom out to 1

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I need to zoom in to the pointer location and the maximum zoom out location would be set to 1.
the image is uplaoded to the canvas from the local system.
Below is my js code snippet:

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

document.getElementById("uploader").onchange = function(e) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = e.target.result;
    image.onload = function() {
      var img = new fabric.Image(image);
      img.set({
        left: 100,
        top: 60
      });
      img.scaleToWidth(1125);
      canvas.add(img).setActiveObject(img).renderAll();
    }
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
}
canvas.on('mouse:wheel', function(opt) {
    var delta = opt.e.deltaY;
    var zoom = canvas.getZoom();
    zoom *= 0.999 ** delta;
    if (zoom > 20) zoom = 20;
    if (zoom < 0.01) zoom = 0.01;
    //canvas.setZoom(zoom);
    const center = canvas.getCenter();
    const centerPoint = new fabric.Point(center.left , center.right);
    canvas.setZoom(zoom);
    opt.e.preventDefault();
    opt.e.stopPropagation();
  })
```

HTML file:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="1500" height="844" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

To set max zoom out change this `if (zoom < 0.01) zoom = 0.01;` to if (zoom < 1) zoom = 1;

Answer (score 0):

you need to use this code

```
canvas.zoomToPoint({ x: opt.e.offsetX, y: opt.e.offsetY }, zoom);
```

instead of

```
const center = canvas.getCenter();
const centerPoint = new fabric.Point(center.left , center.right);
canvas.setZoom(zoom);
```